# C# DbContext Lambda return records combine duplicate column values into csv

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core

I am trying to understand how to display the Models column as a CSV of the different Models for each make. So the results would look something like

Ford, "F150, Mustang"
Toyota, "Supra, Camry"
Honda, "Accord, S2000"
Chevy, "Camaro"

I can do a simple GroupBy but for Lambda I am not even sure this is possible to do.

Also I am using EF Core 3.1

Example DB

https://rextester.com/VIBO8596

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cars](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Make] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Model] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Cars] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Cars] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Cars] ([Id], [Make], [Model]) VALUES (1, N'Ford', N'F150')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Cars] ([Id], [Make], [Model]) VALUES (2, N'Ford', N'Mustang')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Cars] ([Id], [Make], [Model]) VALUES (3, N'Toyota', N'Supra')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Cars] ([Id], [Make], [Model]) VALUES (4, N'Toyota', N'Camry')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Cars] ([Id], [Make], [Model]) VALUES (5, N'Honda', N'Accord')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Cars] ([Id], [Make], [Model]) VALUES (6, N'Honda', N'S2000')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Cars] ([Id], [Make], [Model]) VALUES (7, N'Chevy', N'Camaro')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Cars] OFF
GO
```

Comment: Do you have the LINQ query you are using? Once you do `GroupBy` then you can use `String.Join` on the groups. What version of EF Core?

Comment: Found the issue but just to show the LINQ query

Cars.GroupBy(y=>y.Make).Select(g=>new
               {
                  Models = string.Join(",",g.Select(i=>i.Model))
               }).ToList()

Comment: That failed due to issues with Grouping on entities but you can group on objects. 
it is my understanding ef core 3.1 has an issue with that.

Comment: Yes, EF Core 3.1 can only translate `GroupBy` to SQL if there is an aggregate function in the final projection. There is an open issue being worked to improve that.